# Conversion error from string to unsigned char

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on opencv. I am reading color values(in the form: 123,32,123) from a text file. I need to insert these values into vector(Vec3b)origColors. Below is my code.

```
ifstream myfile;
string line;
string delimiter = ",";
string temp;
vector<uchar> colors;
vector<Vec3b> origColors;
myfile.open("DedicatedColors.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        while(line.find(",",0) != string::npos)
        {
            size_t pos = line.find(",",0);
            temp = line.substr(0, pos);
            line.erase(0,pos+1);
            unsigned char* val=new unsigned char[temp.size() + 1]();
            copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), val);
            colors.push_back(val); //Error Reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const unsigned char') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'unsigned char *'
        }
        dedColors.push_back(Vec3b(colors[0],colors[1],colors[2]));
        colors.clear();
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Could someone please help me fix this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to convert the values in the string to actual integers before adding them to your vector. See `std::stoi`.

Comment: You're trying to pass an unsigned char* to a vector of unsigned chars. Those don't convert.

Comment: @PeterGoldsborough: How can I fix that?

Comment: Just one more note: Whenever you think you need `new something[..]`, you should try `vector<something>` first. It's much easier to handle, in particular you avoid the memory leak in the code above.

Comment: Same goes for char pointers and std::string. These containers were created to make interaction with primitive types easier and less error prone. On another note, if any of these answers solved your problem, please mark the appropriate one as accepted by clicking the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Error Reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const unsigned char') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'unsigned char *'"

You have a vector of unsigned chars, whose `push_back()` method only takes unsigned chars, whereas you are trying to push back an unsigned char *pointer*. If you really need to use unsigned char * and can't just use `std::string`, your colors vector will have to be `std::vector<unsigned char*>`.

Assuming Vec3B only accepts `std::vector<unsigned char*>`, I'd actually be inclined to use std::string till the very end, at which point you can call `std::string::c_str` to get a null terminated string.

Like so:

```
std::ifstream myfile("DedicatedColors.txt");

std::string line;

std::vector<Vec3b> origColors;

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(myfile,line))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> colors;

        std::string::const_iterator last, itr;

        last = itr = line.begin();

        while (std::find(itr, line.end(), ',') != line.end())
        {
            colors.push_back(std::string(last, itr));

            last = itr++;
        }

        dedColors.push_back(Vec3b(colors[0].c_str(),colors[1].c_str(),colors[2].c_str()));
    }
}
```

EDIT: I actually just noticed that you might be trying to convert the RGB values to unsigned chars and not actually use the string as you are now.

Then, have an `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `std::vector<std::string>` and use `std::stoi` to convert the RGB values you get as an `std::string` from `std::getline` to an int, and then pass them like this:

`colors.push_back(std::stoi(std::string(last, itr)));`

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you are trying to `push_back` an `unsigned char*` into a vector which only accepts `unsigned char` on the following line:

```
colors.push_back(val);
```

If you have access to the boost library, you can try the following code (not tested):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
// ... <your code> ...
while (getline(myfile, line)) {
    vector<string> colors;
    boost::split(line, colors, boost::is_any_of(','));
    dedColors.push_back(Vec3b(boost::lexical_cast<uchar>(colors[0]),
                              boost::lexical_cast<uchar>(colors[1]),
                              boost::lexical_cast<uchar>(colors[2])));
}
// ... <continue with your code> ...
```